# Old Chinese romanization using a letter that looks like a "3"

Tags: historical-linguistics, chinese, romanization

I know something about both Chinese and philology, but not much, so please explain like I'm 20. :)

I'm looking at [a text on Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Sacred_Books_of_the_East_-_Volume_3.djvu/36) dealing with "the [Shû King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Documents)". It refers to "Mo-3ze" (Mo-zi) and "Hsün-3ze" ([Xun-zi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xun_Kuang)), and someone called "3o *Kh*iû-ming" — where I'm using the ASCII letter "3" to represent the crazy, on-beyond-zebra letter that the typesetter actually used.

[image: on beyond zebra]

In lowercase it looks kind of like a cursive *z* or an [ezh](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0292/index.htm), but in uppercase I have no idea what's going on: it's like a 3 with cleavage, plus a circumflex accent hanging off its *lower* horn.

Notice that this Romanization system also seems to use significant italics; e.g. "*K*ing" is a different word from "King". (And in both cases "K" denotes what we'd call "J" these days — as in "Peking".)

What is the name and/or Unicode codepoint of this character? What sound is it supposed to represent? And whose Romanization system are we looking at here?

Comment: Typographically speaking, the fancy things are Fraktur style z and Z. I have no information on the transcription system used, unfortunately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [Legge Romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legge_romanization), as taken from the 1879 volume of *Sacred Books of the East*. It is a transcription of the "Mandarin" speech of 19th-century Beijing, which is slightly different to both later transcriptions of standard Mandarin e.g. Wade-Giles.

The symbol under question bears most phonetic resemblance to the zemlja of the Cyrillic script, з, although it is probably just a z but [written in Fraktur](http://interglacial.com/~sburke/stuff/legge_yijing_transliterations.html) as opposed to Italic script. It represents the sound of z- in Pinyin, the alveolar affricate, which had a wider distribution than in current standard Mandarin.

Note also that k is different from *k*.

Comment: What is the significance of writing "зze" instead of just something like "зe"?

Comment: Wow, you are correct, my mystery character "" is indeed just a plain old "Z" in Fraktur — that Unicode character ([U+1D585 MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL Z](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d585/index.htm)) looks exactly the same on my screen, in my browser's default font, as it does in that typeface from 1879! I had no idea.

Comment: Ah, I just realized, maybe in "зze" the "ze" is meant to indicate that the vowel following "з" is basically a syllabic fricative [z], instead of a normal schwa which would be represented by "e" alone.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Thank you for digging out the Unicode: I had an inkling it was in there somewhere.

Comment: @sumelic I don't believe there is a зe... on the talk page of the Wikipedia article it has a list. Pinyin ze would be зeh (e.g. the reference to [Mei Ȝeh](http://www.sacred-texts.com/cfu/sbe03/sbe03004.htm])  / [Mei Ze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mei_Ze) / 梅賾)